# Getting a list of locals on the iPhone

Tags: ios, google-maps, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

How do I get a list of e.g. Restaurants around me? As far as I can see, google enables JS requests only, right? I would not want to use the WebView for that. Are there any other ways to get it? May be not Google?
I'm wondering because it's such a common task, but I've found no info on the net about it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's REST API can of course be used from non-JavaScript environments as well:
This returns a list of restaurants in Miami - in Json format:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=restaurants%20miami

This is a Json implementation in Objective-C:
https://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Examples:

- http://iosdevelopertips.com/networking/json-framework-for-iphone.html
- http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/json-framework-for-iphone-part-2.html

Comment: actually part 2 does not seem to be linked:
http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/json-framework-for-iphone-part-2.html